# is cross_validation module removed from sklearn? if yes since which version?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am reproducing this [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html) with latest version (v0.20.3) of sklearn.

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

end up with

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from sklearn import cross_validation
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation'

is cross_validation module removed from sklearn? if yes since which version? what is the substitute?

Comment: The doc you're linking to is for version 0.16. Since version 0.18 sklearn has no `cross_validation` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cross_validation` module was deprecated in version 0.20 of `scikit-learn`. You can now use the module `model_selection` instead. Read more about Model Selection [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection). The `model_selection` module is available since version 0.18. See the [release notes of 0.18](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.18.html#version-0-18).